# Sqlite null dataset even if there is data in datatable.rows

Tags: c#, sqlite, datatable, dataset

I want to query some data using

```
DataTable dt = null;
SQLiteCommand mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);  

mycommand.CommandText = sql;  

SQLiteDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();  

dt.Load(reader);
```

the Dataset of DataTable returns null but row count > 0 i.e. dt.dataset is null but dt.rows >0 . What should i do to get a filled dataset?

Thank you for your time.
Ferda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is only loading a DataTable, not a complete DataSet. I would change your code a bit so that you're using a DataAdapter to fill the DataSet:

```
var ds = new DataSet();

mycommand.CommandText = sql;
SQLLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLLiteDataAdapter(mycommand);
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: Thank you this will probably return a filled dataset. But i need a datatable with a filled dataset. not a dataset itself alone.

Comment: Hello,do you have an idea to fix this problem?

Comment: @Ferda-Ozdemir - You can use the DataSet to get the DataTable. ds.Tables[0] should give you the table (which, in turn, should have the DataSet filled).

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to use directly datatable not datatabe.dataset so the problem is solved. 
Thank you for you help
Ferda